# Using apache tiles to create customizable ui elements

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, tiles

I've looked for various tiles documentation and it seems that it's mostly used for layouting, so what I'm saying is that on a template each attribute is used once.

I want to create a reusable ui component template, so I want to pass attribute named "type". Let's assume that "type" is used multiple times on that template. In each place it's used I need to write `tiles:insertAttribute`. For custom jsp tag I just declare attributes on top of the tag and then can access declared attributes through `${attribute}` syntax.

Is there a better way to reuse the same attribute in tiles rather than write `tiles:insertAttribute` every time in the template. Also tiles attribute usage is not highlighted in intellij idea, comparing to custom jsp tag attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to reuse the same attribute in tiles rather than write tiles:insertAttribute every time in the template.

If you're happy that tiles:insertAttribute is only executed once and want to reuse the result multiple times do…

```
<c:set var="attribute">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="type" />
</c:set>

${attribute}
${attribute}
${attribute}
```

> Also tiles attribute usage is not highlighted in intellij idea, comparing to custom jsp tag attributes.

I don't know IntelliJ, but as long as the taglib is correct and the tld found then usually the editor highlights everything correctly. You could always try NetBeans.